# IF statement with four or more "OR" in the statement

Tags: php, sql, html

I'm just learn PHP code and I have a IF statement below which does not seem to work.  I have other IF statement like below but with 3 or less OR statement and they seem to work just find.

```
      if ($AT_Med_1_3 == '' or $AT_Med_1_3 == NULL or $AT_Med_1_3 == ' ' or $AT_Med_1_3 = 'None')
      {`enter code here`
//          Echo 'Doing $AT_ Input';
          ?>
 <select name="AT_Med_1_3">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="Oral_Zofran">Oral Zofran</option>
        <option value="IV_Zofran">IV_Zofran</option>
        <option value="Oxygen">Oxygen</option>
        <option value="Ibuprofen">Ibuprofen</option>
        <option value="Aetaminothen">Aetaminothen</option>
        <option value="Upinephrne">Upinephrne</option>
        <option value="Xopenex">Xopenex</option>
        <option value="Albuterol">Albuterol</option>
        <option value="Valium">Valium</option>
        <option value="Magnesiunsulphate">Magnesiunsulphate</option>
        <option value="Diphenhyamine">Diphenhyamine</option>
        <option value="Ketorolac">Ketorolac</option>
        <option value="Promethazion">Promethazion</option>
        <option value="Oral_Fluids_Soup">Oral Fluids Soup</option>
        <option value="Oral_Fluids_Electrolyte">Oral Fluids Electrolyte</option>
        <option value="Oral_Fluids_Water">Oral Fluids Water</option>        
      </select> 
          <?php
      }  else {
//          echo 'Showing $AT_';
          echo $AT_Med_1_3;
          echo nl2br("\n");
      }
?>
```

If I change the IF statement to several If else statement it work but is ugly code

```
      <?php
//      if ($AT_Med_1_1 == '' or $AT_Med_1_1 == NULL or $AT_Med_1_1 == ' ' or $AT_Med_1_1 = 'None')
    if ($AT_Med_1_1 == '')      
{
    goto test1;
} else if ($AT_Med_1_1 == NULL)
{
    goto test1;
} else if ($AT_Med_1_1 == ' ')
{
    goto test1;
} else if ($AT_Med_1_1 == 'None')
{
    goto test1;
}
    goto test;          

//          Echo 'Doing Input';
test1:         
          ?>
      <select name="AT_Med_1_1">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="Oral_Zofran">Oral Zofran</option>
        <option value="IV_Zofran">IV_Zofran</option>
        <option value="Oxygen">Oxygen</option>
        <option value="Ibuprofen">Ibuprofen</option>
        <option value="Aetaminothen">Aetaminothen</option>
        <option value="Upinephrne">Upinephrne</option>
        <option value="Xopenex">Xopenex</option>
        <option value="Albuterol">Albuterol</option>
        <option value="Valium">Valium</option>
        <option value="Magnesiunsulphate">Magnesiunsulphate</option>
        <option value="Diphenhyamine">Diphenhyamine</option>
        <option value="Ketorolac">Ketorolac</option>
        <option value="Promethazion">Promethazion</option>
        <option value="Oral_Fluids_Soup">Oral Fluids Soup</option>
        <option value="Oral_Fluids_Electrolyte">Oral Fluids Electrolyte</option>
        <option value="Oral_Fluids_Water">Oral Fluids Water</option>        
      </select>
          <?php
          goto endtest;
 //     }  else {
//          echo 'Showing $AT_';

test: 
          echo $AT_Med_1_1;
          echo nl2br("\n");
endtest:          
//      }
?>
```

I'm open to so better suggestion on how to code this IF statement.

Comment: your last comparison is actually an assignment. = instead of ==.

Comment: this one `$AT_Med_1_3 = 'None'` should be test with `==`

Answer (score 2):

I think your main issue is the `=` instead of `==`, however to simplify the `if`, `trim()` will remove any whitespace to `''` and `empty()` checks for `''` and `null`:

**PHP < 5.5.0**

```
$AT_Med_1_1 = trim($AT_Med_1_1);
if (empty($AT_Med_1_1) || $AT_Med_1_1 == 'None')
```

**PHP >= 5.5.0**

```
if (empty(trim($AT_Med_1_1)) || $AT_Med_1_1 == 'None')
```

Keep in mind that `empty()` will also see `false` and `0` values (`"0"` and `0.0`) as empty.

Also `||` is the proper OR operator in your case and most cases.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  Your suggestion worked great.